# Split Fullname in Firstname and Lastname

Tags: objective-c

How can I split a full name in `First Name` and `Last Name`.

```
NSString *fullName = @"John Luke Morite";
NSString *firstName = [[fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]; //John
NSString *lastName = ?? // Luke Morite
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do there but just two things you might want to think about. 1) Not every language uses "space" to separate words. 2) Not every language places the family name / surname last.

Comment: In addition, there are last names which have spaces in them (de Jesus, de la Cruz, etc.)

Comment: @Luciano Nascimento i've just been wondering. These full names. Are you taking them from Facebook?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist thanks for the tips. My application target only Brazilian market and here is exactly like that. Anyway, I'll be careful in the next projects!

Comment: @AndreyChernukha yes, some names I take from Facebook. Theres any possible problem?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento Facebook provides first_name field. You don't have to split it yourself. you'll get what the user has entered as their first name.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha the problem is in my `backend` that I save as a fullName, so I need to split then again to call an external `API` that requires split  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *fullName = @"John Luke Morite";
NSString *firstName = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]; //John
NSString *lastName = [fullName substringFromIndex:[fullName rangeOfString:firstName].length + 1];
```

Comment: This will crash if fullName is one word with no spaces. Before setting lastName, do a check for fullName.length > firstName.length

Answer (score 6):

A better way:

```
NSString *fullName = @"John Luke Morite";
NSRange range = [fullName rangeOfString:@" "];
NSString *fname = [fullName substringToIndex:range.location];
NSString *lname = [fullName substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
```

Comment: it will crash when full name string is empty or 1 char.

Answer (score 2):

Here the strategy is looking for the first space, and taking remaining characters

```
NSString *fullName = @"John Luke Morite";
NSRange range = [fullName rangeOfString:@" "];
NSString *lastName = [fullName substringFromIndex:range.length+1];
```

Comment: it will crash on fullName with a space char. " "

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split` to acheive this:

```
   let text = "Stack Overflow Z"
   var fullNameArr = text.split(separator: " ", maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: true)
   let firstName: String = String(fullNameArr.first ?? "")
   let lastName: String =  fullNameArr.count > 0 ? String(fullNameArr[1]) : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the codes in the other answers will crash in different situations. My approach is Messy but works without crashes (Objective-C):

```objectivec
NSString *fullName = @"Mehdi Mousavi Bakhtiari";
NSString *firstName = @"";
NSString *lastName = @"";
if (fullName != nil && fullName.length > 0) {
   NSArray<NSString *> *parts = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
   if (parts != nil && parts.count > 0) {
         firstName = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
         if (parts.count > 1)
            for (int i = 1; i < parts.count; i++) {
               lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", lastName, (NSString *)[parts objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
   }
}
if (lastName != nil && lastName.length > 0)
   lastName = [lastName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"first name: %@", firstName);
NSLog(@"middle name and last name: %@", lastName);
```